# Zend Framework Clearing Cache

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching

I'm using this code to cache an array in zend framework :

```
$frontendOptions = array(
    'lifetime' => 24 * 3600 * 7, // cache lifetime of 7 day
    'automatic_serialization' => true
);

$backendOptions = array(
    // Directory where to put the cache files
    'cache_dir' => APPLICATION_PATH .'/../tmp'
);

// getting a Zend_Cache_Core object
$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core',
    'File',
    $frontendOptions,
    $backendOptions);

$CacheName = ('VOUCHER_MANAGEMENT');

$CacheResult = $cache->load($CacheName);

if($CacheResult === false)
    //make cache
else 
    //use cache
```

Now how can I clear the cache manually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.cache.theory.html#zend.cache.clean) a single call of the `remove()` method would suffice, i.e. to remove a specific cache item:

```
$cache->remove($CacheName);
```

If you want to clean the outdated cache items, then call the `clean()` method:

```
$cache->clean(Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_OLD);
```

To remove all items in the cache:

```
$cache->clean(Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL);
```

Comment: That is correct. would you please give us a link to documentation where you found these info on?

Comment: It's in the first line of the text - click on the word `documentation`.