# Zend(ZF1) - how to clear cache

Tags: caching, zend-framework

I have updated the app.ini file but somewhere someone wrote this code to have used cache. How can I clear the cache?

```
    static $configuration;

    if (!$configuration) {
        if (Zend_Registry::isRegistered("configuration")) {
            $configuration = Zend_Registry::get("configuration");
        }
        else {
            $cache = self::getCache();

            if (!$configuration = $cache->load("configuration")) {
                $configuration = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . "/config/app.ini", APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT);
                $cache->save($configuration, "configuration");
            }

            Zend_Registry::set("configuration", $configuration);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zend Framework Clearing Cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129925/zend-framework-clearing-cache)

Comment: The way I was looking for was actually to restart memcached