# HTML/PHP/SQL - Save a HTML page

Tags: php, html, sql

Currently I'm working on an application and i have a problem. I want to display an html page but the probem is : there is a lot of data/query behind the page. Is it possible to save the html page with the data every morning and then display the html page saved ? I dont want to load the data every time I load the page because the loading is really long.

I'm working with ZendFramwork and Oracle.

Comment: Of course it is possible, but implementing your own caching mechanism is probably a waste of your time as there are good caching solutions available on every level (web-server, php, database, etc.). You are probably already using some of them.

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Comment: Search information about Cache (eg. Redis, Varnish,...) and try to implement it ! The idea is to do a task one time and re-use the result instead of redoing the action. You can do it at different level (server, brower...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use either local storage or session storage for this.
HTML web storage provides two objects for storing data on the client:

- window.localStorage - stores data with no expiration date
- window.sessionStorage - stores data for one session (data is lost when the browser tab is closed)

Use this link to learn more (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use GitHub Pages, write a script in any language to send data in GitHub web page on your decided time and all done your html page in dynamic but act as a static and loads in no time

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use frontend cache.
There are at least 3 versions of Zend Framework, but the caching si very similar.

For Zend 1 there is some theory https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.cache.theory.html#zend.cache.clean

Best way is set frontend cache in routes
For that, use this in your router definition file

```
addRoute($router, [
    'url' => "[your-path]",
    'defaults' => [
        'controller'    => '[controller-name]',
        'action'        => '[action-name]',
        'cache'         => [TIME-OF-CACHE] // 2 hours = 7200
    ]
]);
```

Then, if you really want to delete this cache every morning, you should do it manually, by some CRON script.

For that, try to use this
[Zend Framework Clearing Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129925/zend-framework-clearing-cache)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

1. You need a cron job that runs the script (the HTML file) every morning
2. Add [ob_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) to beginning of your HTML file
3. Save the buffer into a file :)

```
    <?php

    ob_start();

    // Display that HTML file here. You don't need to change anything.

    // Add this to the end of your file to output everything into a file.
    $out = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    file_put_contents('cached.html', $out);
    ?>
```